# How to see the transformed dataset when using plm package in R for fixed effects?

Tags: r, plot, panel-data, plm

Is there a way to display the dataset that has been transformed when using fixed effects with the plm package in r? I also would like to plot the fitted values and the residuals but I think that's not possible because the number of observations is different.

```
IVpan <- plm(log(Y) ~ log(X) + log(W1) + log(W2) + log(W3)| log(W1) + log(W2) + log(W3) + log(Z1),
             model = "within",
             data = output,
             index = c("countryIdentifier","year"),
             effect = "twoways")
```

```
plot(fitted(IVpan), ResIVpan, xlab = "Fitted Values", ylab = "Residuals", main = "Residuals vs. Fitted Values")
```

Comment: Use `model.matrid(<your_model>)` and `pmodel.response(<your_model>)` for the transformed data of dependend variables and response variable, respectively.

Comment: For the other question about fitted and residuals, it is unclear to me why the number of observations should be different. You `plot`-code shows you refer to different objects for this, so a difference would come at no suprise?